# Jinja2 html buttons: Catch POST on different pages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-api-python-client

I've got a GAE-app that uses Jinja2 templates to serve its html pages.

Now in my main python file I've got one class, mainhandler, with a GET and a POST method. This all works for the welcome screen where there is a button to do something. When the button is clicked, the POST method is invoked which calls a second page.

I can't find anything about how to catch the button events on the second page, result.html. And make it progress methods in the main python file.

So: "How can I work with errorMail and toCalendar buttons on result.html?

This is my main file:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*- 

import webapp2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

from format import formatFile

import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(secret)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

    #processes the file and shows the results
    def post(self):
        # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
        http = decorator.http()

        service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http,
           developerKey='secret')

        # Make a list of calendars
        calendar_list = service.calendarList().list().execute()

        totalList = formatFile(self.request.get('file'))

        template_values = {"totalList": totalList, "calendar_list": calendar_list}

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('result.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

This is page index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
    <div><label>Select file:</label</div>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is page result.html:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head> 
    <body>
        <h3>De volgende data staat klaar voor je agenda:</h3>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <th>Dag</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Tijd</th>
                <th>Omschrijving</th>
            </tr>
                 {% for line in totalList %}
                <tr>
                    {% for item in line %}
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
            </tr>        
            {% endfor %}
        </table>

        <br>
        <b>Selecteer de agende waar de diensten in geplaatst worden:</b>
        <br>
        <select>
            {% for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items'] %}
            <option value=>{{ calendar_list_entry['summary'] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br>

        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="toCalendar" value="In kalender plaatsen">
        </form>
        <br>
        <b>Uitvoer incorrect? Klik dan op onderstaande knop om foutmeldings-email te sturen.</b>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="errorMail" value="Uitvoer incorrect!">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to receive buttons events. You receive the form data (including the buttons) in the post like the self.request.get('file')

You can add more than one button to a post.
Every form can have its own post handler, by adding an action:

index.html (results in post to /result1):

```
<form action="/result1" method="post">
```

result.html (results in post to /result2):

```
<form action="/result2" method="post">
    <input id="toCalender " type="submit" name="toCalendar" value="In kalender plaatsen">
    <br>
    <b>Uitvoer incorrect? Klik dan op onderstaande knop om foutmeldings-email te sturen.</b>
    <input id="errorMail" type="submit" name="errorMail" value="Uitvoer incorrect!">
</form>
```

Comment: Do I need to add handlers in app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True) ?

Comment: You can add a handler for every post, but you can also look for the path and find out whitch page has posted / submitted data.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a bit about that in your answer?

Comment: Option one: add a seperate handler class for /result2. You only have to handle the post. Option two: The path is in: self.request.path The post of the MainHandler: if self.request.path == 'result2' ....

Comment: For the second option the handler / regex looks like this: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/.*', MainHandler), ], debug=True)                                         
And the last lines in your app.yaml contain: - url: /.*
  script: main.py